# Why export default doesn't work in this simple code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module, export

Why when I use export default on index.js module it says:
export 'appReducers' (imported as 'appReducers') was not found in './reducers/index' (possible exports: default), but when I change it to module.exports the error go away, why is that?

At redux.js

```
import { appReducers } from './reducers/index'

const Store = () => {
  console.log(appReducers);
}

export default Store
```

in index.js

```
const appReducers = "hello world";
export default appReducers
```

in app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import Store from './redux'

function App() {
  Store();
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `import { appReducers } from`  That does not import the default..   That syntax is for importing something called `appReducers`, if you want the default remove the `{}`

Comment: Thanks, i can't believe I didn't know the difference until now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `redux.js`. Instead of

```
import { appReducers } from './reducers/index'
```

You need

```
import appReducers from './reducers/index'
```

What you were doing before was a named import, not a default import.

Comment: omg that's such a stupic mistake, thanks for your reply